# Neo4j: REST API slower when using parameters

Tags: java, database, neo4j, cypher

I use REST API to perform a query and I have performance issue when I use `parameters`.

```
{
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" : "MATCH (n:NetworkElement)-[:Attribute]-(r:Realm) WHERE n.tag IN {tags} RETURN r.name, collect(n.tag)",
    "parameters" : {
      "tags" : [
  "tag1",
  "tag2",
  "tag3", ...]
    }
  } ]
}
```

This query take **5s**. This is very long.

I try now to include the tags arry inside the statement :

```
{
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" : "MATCH (n:NetworkElement)-[:Attribute]-(r:Realm) WHERE n.tag IN [\"tag1\",\"tag2\",\"tag3\", ...] RETURN r.name, collect(n.tag)",
    "parameters" : {}
  } ]
}
```

And now the query take only **40ms** ?

Someone can explain me ? Give me some optimization way ?

Thanks in advance

Edit 2015-05-27
After test with 2.2.2 the problem occur but in different condition :

I run this query without parameters :

```
{
   "statements": [
       {
           "statement" : "PROFILE MATCH (ne:NetworkElement {_type:'interface'})-[:Connect*1..]->(s:NetworkElement) WHERE s.tag IN [\"mytag\"] RETURN s.tag, collect(ne.tag)",
           "parameters" : {}

       }
       ]
}
```

The query execute in ~100ms without cache, the plan is :

```
{  
   "root":{  
      "operatorType":"EagerAggregation",
      "DbHits":1468,
      "Rows":1,
      "version":"CYPHER 2.2",
      "KeyNames":"s.tag",
      "EstimatedRows":0,
      "planner":"COST",
      "identifiers":[  
         "collect(ne.tag)",
         "s.tag"
      ],
      "children":[  
         {  
            "operatorType":"Projection",
            "LegacyExpression":"ne",
            "Rows":734,
            "DbHits":1468,
            "EstimatedRows":0,
            "identifiers":[  
               "  UNNAMED46",
               "ne",
               "s",
               "s.tag"
            ],
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "operatorType":"Filter",
                  "LegacyExpression":"(ne:NetworkElement AND ne._type == {  AUTOSTRING0})",
                  "Rows":734,
                  "DbHits":3402,
                  "EstimatedRows":0,
                  "identifiers":[  
                     "  UNNAMED46",
                     "ne",
                     "s"
                  ],
                  "children":[  
                     {  
                        "operatorType":"VarLengthExpand(All)",
                        "ExpandExpression":"(s)-[  UNNAMED46:Connect*]->(ne)",
                        "Rows":1134,
                        "DbHits":2269,
                        "EstimatedRows":0,
                        "identifiers":[  
                           "  UNNAMED46",
                           "ne",
                           "s"
                        ],
                        "children":[  
                           {  
                              "operatorType":"NodeUniqueIndexSeek",
                              "Index":":NetworkElement(tag)",
                              "Rows":1,
                              "DbHits":1,
                              "EstimatedRows":0.9999999999971109,
                              "identifiers":[  
                                 "s"
                              ],
                              "children":[  

                              ]
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Now I run the same query with parameters :

```
{
   "statements": [
       {
           "statement" : "PROFILE MATCH (ne:NetworkElement)-[:Connect*1..]->(s:NetworkElement) WHERE ne._type = {endNeType} AND s.tag IN {startTags} RETURN s.tag, collect(ne.tag)",
           "parameters" : {
               "endNeType" : "interface",
               "startTags" : ["mytag"]
           }

       }
       ]
}
```

The query take 980ms to execute and the plan is not the same :

```
{  
   "root":{  
      "operatorType":"EagerAggregation",
      "DbHits":1468,
      "Rows":1,
      "version":"CYPHER 2.2",
      "KeyNames":"s.tag",
      "EstimatedRows":0,
      "planner":"COST",
      "identifiers":[  
         "collect(ne.tag)",
         "s.tag"
      ],
      "children":[  
         {  
            "operatorType":"Projection",
            "LegacyExpression":"ne",
            "Rows":734,
            "DbHits":1468,
            "EstimatedRows":0,
            "identifiers":[  
               "  UNNAMED26",
               "ne",
               "s",
               "s.tag"
            ],
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "operatorType":"Filter",
                  "LegacyExpression":"(any(-_-INNER-_- in {startTags} where s.tag == -_-INNER-_-) AND s:NetworkElement)",
                  "Rows":734,
                  "DbHits":104427,
                  "EstimatedRows":0,
                  "identifiers":[  
                     "  UNNAMED26",
                     "ne",
                     "s"
                  ],
                  "children":[  
                     {  
                        "operatorType":"VarLengthExpand(All)",
                        "ExpandExpression":"(ne)-[  UNNAMED26:Connect*]->(s)",
                        "Rows":34809,
                        "DbHits":105113,
                        "EstimatedRows":0,
                        "identifiers":[  
                           "  UNNAMED26",
                           "ne",
                           "s"
                        ],
                        "children":[  
                           {  
                              "operatorType":"NodeIndexSeek",
                              "Index":":NetworkElement(_type)",
                              "Rows":35495,
                              "DbHits":35496,
                              "EstimatedRows":0.9999999999971109,
                              "identifiers":[  
                                 "ne"
                              ],
                              "children":[  

                              ]
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have an unique constraint on NetworkElement.tag and index on NetworkElement._type.

Comment: But you don't execute them one after the other? I.e. the first one on cold caches the second one on warmed up caches?

Comment: Do you have an index on `:NetworkElement(tag)` ?

Comment: Yes, I empty cache and I have index on tag.
The index is not in cause, the query is the same so the plan must be the same. And the query with parameters is always long even with the cache

Comment: can you share the visual query plan? and also try to update to 2.2.2 ? There was one issue around this fixed.

Comment: Hi, it seems to be solve in 2.2.2
Thanks

Comment: After more test the problem always occur in 2.2.2 in others conditions.

Comment: Can you report the other conditions as github issue on github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues ?

Comment: It's done : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4357#issuecomment-105896712

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 1 potential index usage, the plan might look different, you can force the other (or both) index lookups with `USING INDEX`

```
MATCH (ne:NetworkElement)-[:Connect*1..]->(s:NetworkElement) 
USING INDEX ne:NetworkElement(_type)
USING INDEX s:NetworkElement(tag)
WHERE ne._type = {endNeType} AND s.tag IN {startTags} 
RETURN s.tag, collect(ne.tag)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response.
I try with only
`USING INDEX s:NetworkElement(tag)`
and it's really better (50ms instead of 900ms)

But for me it's a workaround. I don't understand why the PLAN is not the same with and without parameters ?